# how to add overflow auto to input type in html

Tags: html, css

How to add auto scroll bar to input type.

here is my code.

```
<div class="email">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="description">
</div>
```

Comment: type="text" cannot have a scrolling bar, did you mean to use type="textarea" ?

Comment: if i give as textarea the cursor is showing at the end but the cursor should display in the right side how to change that

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve, do you have an example?

Comment: please provide, any jsfiddle, any example.

Comment: @Roberrrt you can check here fddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/3d3db681/

Comment: Okay, that's the code, but what exactly do you wish to achieve?

Comment: If i click on name,email,phone number the cursor is displaying right side but for description it is displaying at the end of margin need to move cursor little right same as other

Comment: once i click on description the cursor is displaying next to magin-left but for  name,email it is different for description also it should show same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give some padding to your `textarea`

```
textarea {
  resize: none;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```css
.phone, .email, .name, .description {
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
textarea {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
textarea {
 resize: none;
 padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 requestfree">
 
 <div class="name">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name">
 </div>
 <div class="name">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
 </div>
 <div class="email">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
 </div>
 <div class="description">
  <textarea name="description" style="width:25%;overflow:auto;" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
 </div>
 
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about scroll bar. To show scroll bar at right side. use `overflow-y:auto;`

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3d3db681/2/)

Comment: not about the scroll bar i am talking about the cursor when we click on description

Comment: Can you  see that if we click on name,phone,email cursor is starting from the placeholder value in the same for description as well need to change that

Comment: give some padding to textarea as other element

Comment: @KANAYOAUSTINKANE i need to add auto scroll bar to input type="text" or else if we click on text boxes cursors are displaying in different positions need to change that

Comment: @Khurram i am not getting you

Comment: why you don't give form-control class to textarea. It will auto adjust margin like other input element.

Comment: Do you mean when you click on the input field, you want the cursor to be focused at the ending of the text?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<div class="email">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="description" style="overflow:auto;">
</div>
```